# How do I debug an 's3:CreateBucket Access Denied' from CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have a CloudFormation Stack created from a Serverless YAML file.

One of the resources is this:

```
"S3BucketWebRoot": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties": {
        "BucketName": "samhain.today",
        "AccessControl": "PublicRead",
        "WebsiteConfiguration": {
          "IndexDocument": "index.html",
          "ErrorDocument": "404.html"
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm having no problems deploying the Stack files (which includes creating an S3 bucket, itself), but when the Stack starts to get built, I'm getting:

```
    14:38:46 UTC-0500   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::S3::Bucket S3BucketWebRoot API: s3:CreateBucket Access Denied
```

Problem is, the User associated with the Serverless service has, as part of its policy:

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:CreateBucket",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:DeleteBucket",
            "s3:ListBucketVersions"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3::*:*"
        ]
    }
```

How do I even go about debugging this? Either my `Resource` is wrong, or its some other user being used, but that makes no sense because they're attached to an Access Key ID.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to make explicit what @Dancrumb already wrote in a comment to the downvoted answer: What seemed to work for him and me was to replace fine-grained S3 permissions with a single wildcard permission:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
             "s3:*",
             ...
        ]
    }
}
```

I can only speculate for the reason. In an issue report for the Serverless project on Github I saw people mention that they were using a user that is tied to an account that has MFA enabled, which applies in my case, too (the account has MFA, not the user). If **s3:*** is too permissive for you, you may be able to  restrict it "after the fact" with an additional *deny* segment. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to verify this theory.

Comment: I hate that this comment actually solves this problem, but >3 years later I ran into the exact same scenario where s3:CreateBucket produces Access Denied and magically s3:* is accepted. I am using MFA and sam but beyond that, this is absolutely magic

Answer (score 0):

For me I accidentally had a conflicting managed policy it seems

```
            ManagedPolicyArns:
                - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
```

Answer (score -4):

Change the resource to be:

```
"Resource": "*"
```

This will permit the given actions for any resource. Your actions are all related to S3, therefore they will be permitted to operate on any Amazon S3 buckets.

If you want to permit it to only operate on one bucket, use:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME"
```

Comment: I had to set the `Action` to `s3:*` to get it working... any idea why?

Comment: I have no idea. It seems to work fine with specific actions when I create a policy. What error did you receive?